Android Studio Chapter 15 Implicit Intents
I am getting this error when running the most recent version of android studios
error
code
I have attached the error message and the  red line error in my code.
I have seen some threads saying I need to add a URL somewhere but I can't get that to work.
repositories {
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
trying to add url into the settings.gradle 
ive tried adding that in and syncing but it gives me : "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0."

Your problem is that your variable contactUri can be null (it is Uri?), but the first parameter to query() requires a non-null Uri value. Nullability and nullable types are fairly important to Kotlin. For what it's worth, I cover nullability in this chapter of this free book

so take out the ? and it should work?

No, because getData() on an Intent can return null. You need to check to see if you got null and do something else in that case.
